# Securing a folder in ASP.NET web directory

Tags: asp.net, security, password-protection, web-folders

I worked long time back on a website and it has been working fine, recently a problem has been reported, which I need to go through.

In my site there is a folder named repository, which contains files like word and PDF documents and ideally only logged in users are allowed to download them but now it has been observed that anyone who is not logged into the website, can even also download them :(

Is there any wayout to handle it without moving the folder out of the web directory? Like making that folder password protected and only my pages can access the content, any code sample or link will be of high use.

My web application is in ASP.NET 2.0 with C# and server has IIS 6.0.

Thanks in Advance

**Edit:**

My Web.Config has these tags in it:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms slidingExpiration="true" loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="HomePage.aspx" name=".ASPXMAIN" timeout="30">
  </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Comment: I wonder y people vote the question, without giving/commenting any reason for the action, so that the author can improve him/her self.

Comment: I upvoted the question, I think it is a useful question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `<location />` tags in the web.config, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(v=vs.71).aspx

```
  <location path="content">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

See this answer for more links to msdn documentation:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4280257/426894

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, will implement and check it and will get back to you if I find any problem.

Comment: I have put an edit section in my question with the tags in my web.config, shouldn't <deny users="?" /> must stop the unauthorized users from accessing the folder or I am not understanding it properly?

Comment: @ImranBalouch I just posted a simple bit of example usage, not something exactly what you need. Mostly because I have no idea what kind of roles and such you want. Look at the answer I linked, it has msdn docs for everything so you can customize the config exactly as you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this config in your Web.config (location permit you to define path)

This sample use `roles` in order to design profil.

Also use `users` in order to design user.

```
<location path="~/MembersOnly" > 
  <system.web> 
    <authorization> 
      <allow roles="Members"/> 
      <deny users="?" /> 
    </authorization> 
  </system.web> 
</location>
```