# Tools for form authentication in web application on the basis of user role in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I need to implement one website and in this website i want to give access to users on the basis of there roles.
I used Roles and Membership, but i found its based on folder. I want form based authentication.
Is there any tool for this.

Comment: Take a look at this thread, it should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280184/asp-net-membership-roles-web-config-settings

Comment: thanks for your reply. But its not my requirement.In my website there are some menus i want to display menus to users based on there role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you can check a user's role membership, something like this:

```
if (User.IsInRole("admins")) {
    //display the admin menu
} else {
    //display the non-admin menu
}
```

Comment: But if i have more than 10 roles then  i need to check for every role and for every role i need to check for every form ...

Comment: I'm not following exactly what you are trying to do. There are 2 ways to check that a user is in a role. You can use User.IsInRole("rolename") or you can use Roles.GetRolesForUser() which will give you a string array you can check if your role is in there. If you have 10 roles and need to do something different based on each role, then yeah you'll need to check every role.